# Necessary and sufficient condition for $u(x,y,z)$ , $v(x,y,z)$ ,$w(x,y,z)$ are functionally dependent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Show that necessary and sufficient condition for that $u(x,y,z)$ , $v(x,y,z)$ ,$w(x,y,z)$ are functionally dependent through equation $F(u,v,w)= 0$  is $\nabla u\cdot (\nabla v \times \nabla w )$.

[image]

Any clue on this?

What if there are $2$ variable instead of $3$ (say only $u(x,y,z)$ and $v(x,y,z)$ are functionally dependent)?

[image]

Comment: There are no equations or conditions in your question.

Comment: Qn is just that. pls see above images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $F(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z))=0$ and $F$ is differentiable then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\nabla u+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\nabla v={\bf 0}.$$
Note that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}$ are scalars.

Comment: I think i got it. Here is  what i did.
$F_u \nabla u + F_v \nabla v = 0 \implies $ Vector $ \vec{\nabla u} = c\vec{\nabla v}$,where $c=\frac{-F_v}{F_u} = scalar \implies $2vectors are parallel which means $\nabla u \cdot\nabla v = 0$

For converse , choosing $c=\frac{-F_v}{F_u}$ and backtrackng as above. Can i choose such scalar? i have a doubt here.

Comment: For 1st problem, the same way
$F_u \nabla u + F_v \nabla v +F_w \nabla w = 0 \implies $ Vector $ \vec{\nabla u} = a_1\vec{\nabla v} +a_2\vec{\nabla w}$

it means $\vec{\nabla u} ,\vec{\nabla v} ,\vec{\nabla w}$ are coplanar which means volume of paralleoloid formed by these 3 vectors = 0. It means $\nabla u \cdot (\nabla v X \nabla w) = 0$

For converse, can i choose $a_1 = \frac{-F_v}{F_u}, a_2 = \frac{-F_w}{F_u}$ and then backtrack i suppose.
I am having doubt whether can i choose such scalars by hit and trial

Comment: pls have a look

Comment: @anirudhb It seems fine to me.

Comment: Can you tell how you got the expression for the first sum with the 3 variable.

Comment: It's coming $ F_u∇u.dr+F_v∇v.dr+F_w∇w.dr=0 $which is indeed 0  for every component as position vector is perpendicular to gradient. So how got the expression without dr and how the conclusion is coming.we can't remove $dr $ . Can you @Magneto clarify i am also stuck on the same question.

Comment: Since $F(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z))=0$ then when you take differentiate with respect to $x$ we find
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$
This is the first component of the vector equation $F_u \nabla u + F_v \nabla v = 0$. For $F$ with $3$ variables, it is similar.
Do the same for $y$ and $z$. There is no $dr$ here!