# Error in calculating $I=\iint_S (2x^2-y^3)dS$ over cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Evaluate
>   $$I=\iint_S (2x^2-y^3)dS$$ where $S$ is surface of cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ between planes $z=0$ and $z=3$.

Here $\vec {n} = (x/2,y/2,0)$.  By symmetry of cylinder around $y=0$, given integral becomes $I=\iint_S (2x^2)dS $ .

Now projecting on $yz$ plane (let S projection on $yz$ plane be $R$), $$I=\iint_R (2x^2)\frac {dy dz } {(\vec n \cdot \vec i)} = \int_{z=0}^{z-3} \int_{y=-2}^{y=2} 2x dy dz $$

Here again $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}$. Solving above integral I am getting $24 \pi$

But if i use cylindrical coordinates on 1st equation (in 1st line) i am getting $48 \pi$ . 
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi}\int_{z= 0}{3} 2x^2-y^3 dS$$, where $dS=2d\theta dz$  $x=2\cos \theta$, $y = 2 \sin \theta$ 
$$= \iint((16 \cos^2 \theta - 16 \sin^3  \theta d)  \theta dz = 48 \pi.$$

Please point me where i am making error.

Comment: You probably doing sth wrong with your calculation in cylindrical corrdinates. I get $24\pi$.

Comment: in textbook answer is given as $48\pi$

Comment: Just check your computation in cylin.coord again. Is it really $48\pi$ ?.

Comment: extremely sorry. due to latex,i entered integrand wrongly. Pls have a look. My apologies

Comment: i just wanted to know by symmetry about y = 0 given integrand becomes $2x^2$. But why i am getting $24 \pi$ i am not able to find out.

Comment: Just look at your $\vec{n} \cdot \hat{i}$. It should be $x/2$. So the next equality should multiplied by factor $2$.

Comment: i got it. I need to consider 2 projections - front side and back side of cylinder. thnx !

Comment: can u pls havea look at my other doubt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509291/evaluate-surface-integral-over-unit-sphere

Comment: also this Qn - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493477/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-ux-y-z-vx-y-z-wx-y-z-are-f pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation in cylindrical coordinates is correct. We have that $dS=2d\theta dz$ and by simmetry the integral of $y^3$ is zero. Hence
$$I=\iint_S 2x^2dS=\int_{z=0}^3\int_0^{2\pi} (2(2\cos(\theta))^2)2d\theta dz=48\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(\theta)d\theta=48\pi.$$
In cartesian coordinates, your evaluation should be doubled because you are considering just the semicircle given by $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}$ where $x\geq 0$.

An "easy" evaluation can be done by using Gauss divergence theorem.
Let ${\bf F}:=(4x,0,0)$ then 
$$\iint_S 2x^2dS=\iint_S {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\,dS=\int_V\text{div}({\bf F})dV-\iint_D {\bf F}\cdot{\bf n}\,dS=4\cdot(2\pi\cdot 2\cdot 3)-0=48\pi$$
where $V$ is the solid cylinder and $D$ is the union of the two disks at $z=0$ and $z=3$.

Comment: extremely sorry. due to latex,i entered integrand wrongly. Pls have a look. My apologies

Comment: that's the catch. It is actually 2 projections - front cylinder side and backward cylinderside. Brilliant catch! thanks

Comment: can u pls have a look at my other doubt https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509291/evaluate-surface-integral-over-unit-sphere

Comment: also this Qn https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493477/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-ux-y-z-vx-y-z-wx-y-z-are-f pls havea look